# Remove repeated clock hands using set Interval in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, setinterval, clock

Hye, I'm new at canvas. I have issue with my clock. At every call of workinghands() function by setInterval, clock hands ticks forward but the previous hands are not removed. I want to remove the repeated hands on the clock.
In the image of clock you'll see what I want. Not only the long hand repeats itself but also the other two hands.
[click the link to view image of clock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3Eal.png)

```
    function workingHands(context)
    {
        var date = new Date();
        var second = date.getSeconds();
        var minute = date.getMinutes();
        var hour = date.getHours() % 12;

        second = second * Math.PI / 30;
        drawHands(context, second, 125, 2);

        second = date.getSeconds();

        minute = (second * Math.PI / (1800)) + (minute * Math.PI / 30);
        drawHands(context, minute, 100, 5);

        second = date.getSeconds();
        minute = date.getMinutes();

        hour = (second * Math.PI / (10800)) + (minute * Math.PI / 1800) + (hour * Math.PI / 6)
        drawHands(context, hour, 50, 10);
    }
    function drawHands(context, angle, length, width)
    {
        context.translate(18, -7);
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(0, 0);
        context.rotate(angle);
        context.lineTo(0, -length);
        context.lineWidth = width;
        context.lineCap = "round";
        context.stroke();
        context.rotate(-angle);
        context.translate(-18, 7);
    }
    function clockFace(context)
    {
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(centerX, centerY, 140, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.strokeStyle = "black";
        context.lineWidth = "10";
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(centerX, centerY, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.fill = "black";
        context.stroke();

        context.translate(centerX, centerY);
        decorClock(context);
        numbers(context);
    }
    clockFace(context);
    setInterval(workingHands, 1000, context);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's one fundamental thing to remember about canvas - you can't "remove" anything you already drew. So, to avoid those "repeats" you have to clear all canvas and draw everything again, or at least - cover some part - like clockFace.

In your case, it should be something like that:

```
function workingHands(context)
{
    clockFace(context);
    var date = new Date();
    var second = date.getSeconds();
    var minute = date.getMinutes();
    var hour = date.getHours() % 12;

    second = second * Math.PI / 30;
    drawHands(context, second, 125, 2);

    second = date.getSeconds();

    minute = (second * Math.PI / (1800)) + (minute * Math.PI / 30);
    drawHands(context, minute, 100, 5);

    second = date.getSeconds();
    minute = date.getMinutes();

    hour = (second * Math.PI / (10800)) + (minute * Math.PI / 1800) + (hour * Math.PI / 6)
    drawHands(context, hour, 50, 10);
}
```

The only thing that has changed is "clockFace(context);" covering, painting clockface white right before drawing hands.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('c')
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var centerX = canvas.width/2,
     centerY = canvas.height/2;

function workingHands()
    {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        clockFace();
        var date = new Date();
        var second = date.getSeconds();
        var minute = date.getMinutes();
        var hour = date.getHours() % 12;

        second = second * Math.PI / 30;
        drawHands(context, second, 125, 2);

        second = date.getSeconds();

        minute = (second * Math.PI / (1800)) + (minute * Math.PI / 30);
        drawHands(context, minute, 100, 5);

        second = date.getSeconds();
        minute = date.getMinutes();

        hour = (second * Math.PI / (10800)) + (minute * Math.PI / 1800) + (hour * Math.PI / 6)
        drawHands(context, hour, 50, 10);
    }
    function drawHands(context, angle, length, width)
    {
    
        context.save();
        context.translate(centerX, centerX);
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(0, 0);
        context.rotate(angle);
        context.lineTo(0, -length);
        context.lineWidth = width;
        context.lineCap = "round";
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
        context.restore();
    }
    function clockFace()
    {
   
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(centerX, centerY, 140, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.strokeStyle = "black";
        context.lineWidth = "10";
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(centerX, centerY, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.fill = "black";
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
    }
    setInterval(workingHands, 1000);
```

```html
<canvas id='c' width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

Its drawing everytime in canvas, so you need to clear and re-draw.

`context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`